# Two years old potty regression

Tags: toddler, potty-training

My 2 y.o has been potty trained for 3 months. Recently he changed a daycare and started to pee on the floor just for fun. I tried to educate him, but it's only getting worse. If I undress him, he can pee several drops, run to another corner, pee a bit more, and so on. He still poops on the potty.
That started 3 weeks ago, he's wearing pullups since then. Any advices how to handle it?

Answer (score 2):

Does he only do this when you are there to witness it, or does he do it at daycare and at home when you are out of the room too? I'm asking because it could be attention getting behaviour. Naturally, when he begins this inappropriate peeing, you react. You could try simply not reacting at all, walking away when he begins, then later coming back in to clean it up. I know this would be tough to do, but it might work if you completely do not give him attention during and after the act. In addition, try to give him a LOT of attention when you are together. Go overboard with it, and see if his behaviour changes. This could take a few weeks or even more, depending on how long he has been doing this and how strong your reaction has been.